# Using Power Query, can you use an IF statement to determine whether a value is a number in two different columns?

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm attempting to sort a list of two columns containing both numbers and text on whether or not a value is text or a number.

```
if ((Value.Is(Value.FromText([OLD ITEM]), type number) = "TRUE") or if ((Value.Is(Value.FromText([NEW ITEM]), type number) = "TRUE")
then "FIXTURE"
else ""
```

Currently its giving me an error that the second "Value.Is" is incorrect.

Comment: Please show us your full M query, and schema details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used

```
=if Value.Is(Value.FromText([OLD ITEM]), type number) and Value.Is(Value.FromText([NEW ITEM]), type number)
then "ITEM"
else "")
```

It didn't need the ="TRUE".

Answer (score 0):

to test for a number (**4** but not **"4"** and not **a**) add column, custom column, with

```
= Value.Is([Column1Name], type number) or Value.Is([Column2Name], type number)
```

Comment: I figured it out.  I was using the if function to look for a text that was actually a boolean value.